# Error: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Inside of my application when I visit one of my html pages I want the code inside of the controller to execute as fast as possible. The problem is I am recieveing the error:

> Error: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D':
>   The source width is 0.

The controller is taking an image and then applying a filter to it and then creating a brand new image. This brand new image is then stored in a variable. When I click one of the buttons, the appropriate filter is applied by taking the image stored in the variable and applying it to $scope.mainImage in which then angularjs takes over with its 2 way data binding and shows the new filtered image on the screen. The problem is when the view loads initially the original image (img/testing.jpg) appears, but the error is in the console and non of the new images are created.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
app.controller('PhotoController', function ($ionicPlatform, $scope, $state, $localstorage, $ionicHistory, $http, $cordovaCapture, $cordovaFile) {

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function ($cordovaStatusbar) {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      $scope.mainImage = 'img/testing.jpg';


      /*
         Alot more code here
      */

      // =================================
      // piece of code where the error is occurring:

       filterImage: function(filter, args) {
        console.log("Filter = " + filter);
        if (this.pixelData) { // if multiple filters are applied
          console.log("inside this.pixelData");
          this.ctx.putImageData(this.pixelData, 0, 0);
        }
        // !!!!!!!!ERROR OCCUR HERE!!!!!!!!!!! var params = [this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.c.width, this.c.height)]; // !!!!!!!ERROR OCCUR HERE!!!!!!!!!

        for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
          params.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        this.pixelData = this[filter].apply(this, params);
      }

      // =================================

      $scope.img1 = null;
      $scope.img2 = null;

      var originalPhoto = document.getElementById('originalPhoto');

      $scope.img1 = ApplyEffects['reset'](originalPhoto, 'jpeg').src;
      $scope.changeReset = function () {
        $scope.mainImage = $scope.img1;
      };

      $scope.img2 = ApplyEffects['memphis'](originalPhoto, 'jpeg').src;
      $scope.changeMemphis = function () {
        $scope.mainImage = $scope.img2;
      };

    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
   <ion-content>
        <!-- Photo Preview -->
        <section id="photoEffect">

            <figure>
                <img id="originalPhoto" ng-src="{{$parent.mainImage}}" width="200" height="200">
            </figure>

            <button ng-click="$parent.changeReset()">Reset</button>
            <button ng-click="$parent.changeMemphis()">Memphis</button>

        </section>
    </ion-content>
```

If I wrap this seciton of code:

```
        var originalPhoto = document.getElementById('originalPhoto');

            $scope.img1 = ApplyEffects['reset'](originalPhoto, 'jpeg').src;
            $scope.changeReset = function () {
                $scope.mainImage = $scope.img1;
            };

            $scope.img2 = ApplyEffects['memphis'](originalPhoto, 'jpeg').src;
            $scope.changeMemphis = function () {
                $scope.mainImage = $scope.img2;
            };  

});
});
```

inside of a timeout function of say 2 seconds then it will work, but it is very slow. If I set it to a lower timeout of say 0.5 seconds then it is a little quicker, but on some devices it works and other devices it doesn't. I would like this code though to execute as fast as possible.

It seems to me that maybe the original image is not being initialized since it works with the timeout function, but with $ionicPlatform.ready I think it should only run when this is initialized. My timeout solution though to me is too slow and unreliable.

Comment: Remember that a canvas' style width (`canvas.style.width`) and html width  (`canvas.width`) are different, and if they are not the same value, then there will be weirdness.